# "Deno" not recognized in VSC, it's underlined in red. I get the error of "Cannot find name 'Deno'.ts(2304)". In settings, deno is enabled.ings.json,

Tags: typescript, deno

For some reason, Visual Studio Code is not recognizing CLI "Deno.args", etc.  as seen in the code below. I've checked settings.json and deno is enabled.

```
import { readStringDelim } from "https://deno.land/std/io/buffer.ts";
async function tail(fileName: string) {
  const fileReader = await Deno.open(fileName);
  await Deno.seek(fileReader.rid, 0, Deno.SeekMode.End);
  const watcher = Deno.watchFs(fileName);
  for await (const event of watcher) {
    if (event.kind !== "modify") continue;
    for await (const line of readStringDelim(fileReader, "\n")) {
      if (!line) break;
      yield (line.trim());
    }
  }
}
const file = Deno.args[0];
if (!file) {
  console.error("File must be provided");
  Deno.exit(1);
}
for await (const line of tail(file)) {
  console.log("Got line:", line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/getting_started/setup_your_environment#visual-studio-code):

> There is an official extension for Visual Studio Code called [vscode_deno](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno). When installed, it will connect to the language server built into the Deno CLI.
>
> Because most people work in mixed environments, the extension does not enable a workspace as Deno enabled by default, and it requires that the `"deno.enable"` flag to be set. You can change the settings yourself, or you can choose `Deno: Initialize Workspace Configuration` from the command palette to enable your project.
>
> More information can be found in the [Using Visual Studio Code](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/references/vscode_deno/) section of the manual.